# Linq to Nested Lists

Tags: c#, linq, generic-list

Need a little help with a LINQ query.  I have a string that consists of components and subcomponents.  I also have a LINQ query that nicely splits the components and subcomponents up into nested generic lists.

```
List<List<string>> fields = (from a in text.Split(new char[] { '\r' })
                             select a.Split(new char[] { ',' }).ToList()).ToList();
```

I now have some subcomponents that have their own subcomponents delimited by a '-'.  How can I modify the above code to allow for a third nested list using the third delimiter.  Have tried a few LINQ variations but cant get it to work right.  I have very basic LINQ knowledge.  Thanks in advance.

Example:

```
component1,component2,component3.1-component3.2-component3.3,component4
component1,component2,component3,component4.1-component4.2-component4.3,component5,component6.1-component6.2
```

Comment: Define "subcomponents".

Comment: Please post example input values for your `String text`.

Comment: When you have 3 levels of nested lists, you're probably doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with the following Linq query

```
var fields = text.Split('\r')
    .Select(a => a.Split(',')
                  .Select(b => b.Split('-')
                                .ToList())
                  .ToList())
    .ToList();
```

Or in query syntax

```
var fields = (from a in text.Split('\r')
              select (from b in a.Split(',')
                      select b.Split('-').ToList())
                     .ToList())
            .ToList();
```

Note you don't have to create the arrays for the `Split` method as it's defined as a `params` argument.